# Python - Same if statement multiple times in one code block

Tags: python

Consider this code:

```
def say_hi(english: bool, name: str) -> str:
    if name != "":
        if english:
            greeting = f"Hi, {name}!"
    else:
        if english:
            greeting = "Hey there!"
    if english:
        greeting = greeting + "foo bar"
    if not english:
        greeting = "I speak only English, sorry."
    return greeting
```

What is the best way to optimize this code to not have 3 times the same if statmenet (`if english:`) in one block of code? Or, perhaps a different question - does this repetitive if statement code match Python PEP standards?

Comment: What do you expect `greeting` to be if `english` is false?

Comment: `if not english: raise NameError` at the top of the function, then remove the check everywhere else…

Comment: That is not important in this case. The above code serves as an example. That is not a code snippet one should use, but only a code snippet to demonstrate my question.

Comment: This is simply badly structured logic, or at least *inefficiently expressed logic.* You don’t need a PEP for that, and it very much does depend on the specific case how the logic might be expressed in a more compact, yet still maintainable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just reverse the order of `if` statements?

```
def say_hi(english: bool, name: str) -> str:
    if english:
        if name != "":
                greeting = f"Hi, {name}!"
        else:
                greeting = "Hey there!"
        greeting = greeting + "foo bar"
    else:
        greeting = "I speak only English, sorry."
    return greeting
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
def say_hi(english: bool, name: str) -> str:
    if not english:
        greeting = "I speak only English, sorry."
    else:
        greeting = (f"Hi, {name}!" if name else "Hey there!") + "foo bar"
    return greeting
```

Answer (score 1):

- Failing fast. i.e Put the code that fails fast at the top.
- boolen variables should start with "is" where possible

```py
# Without Foo bar
def say_hi_2(is_english_speaker: bool, name: str):
    if not is_english_speaker:
        return "I speak only English, sorry."

    if not name:
        return "Hey There"

    return f"Hi, {name}"

# With foo bar
def say_hi(is_english_speaker: bool, name: str):
    if not is_english_speaker:
        return "I speak only English, sorry."

    greeting_template = "{} foo bar"
    if not name:
        return greeting_template.format("Hey There")

    return greeting_template.format(f"Hi, {name}")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to Python and doesn't need any PEP, it's simply part of writing *Good Code™* and should be applied to any and all code you write. Go through it and apply simplifications step by step to boil it down to its most minimal, simple, understandable form.

I'm using your [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70679127/1) here, since it shows an additional important lesson:

```
def say_hi(english: bool, name: str) -> str:
    if name != "":
        if english:
            greeting = f"Hi, {name}!"
    else:
        if english:
            greeting = "Hey there!"
    if english:
        greeting = greeting + "foo bar"
    return greeting
```

1. Recognise that the first `if..else` branches both contain the same `if english` check, and that both don't do anything if `english` is falsey. So you can reverse that check:

   ```
   if english:
       if name != "":
           greeting = f"Hi, {name}!"
       else:
           greeting = "Hey there!"
   ```
2. Recognise that you could inline this inner `if..else`:

   ```
   if english:
       greeting = f"Hi, {name}!" if name != "" else "Hey there!"
   ```

   This is debatable and depends on your personal preference, but I think it's applicable here.
3. Recognise that you now have the same condition check twice:

   ```
   if english:
       greeting = f"Hi, {name}!" if name != "" else "Hey there!"
   if english:
       greeting = greeting + "foo bar"
   ```

   Condense that to:

   ```
   if english:
       greeting = f"Hi, {name}!" if name != "" else "Hey there!"
       greeting = greeting + "foo bar"
   ```
4. Now something that only existed in your original code: recognise that you now have a bug in your function:

   ```
   def say_hi(english: bool, name: str) -> str:
       if english:
           greeting = f"Hi, {name}!" if name != "" else "Hey there!"
           greeting = greeting + "foo bar"
       return greeting
   ```

   Your function basically doesn't do anything if `english` is falsey, and will produce a `NameError` on the last line. This is now easier to recognise with the simplified logic. So, to acknowledge that behaviour explicitly and produce the exact same behaviour with less code, it would be this:

   ```
   def say_hi(english: bool, name: str) -> str:
       if not english:
           raise NameError

       greeting = f"Hi, {name}!" if name != "" else "Hey there!"
       greeting = greeting + "foo bar"
       return greeting
   ```
5. Recognise that you can condense the last two lines:

   ```
   def say_hi(english: bool, name: str) -> str:
       if not english:
           raise NameError

       greeting = f"Hi, {name}!" if name != "" else "Hey there!"
       return greeting + "foo bar"
   ```

   You *could* condense the last two lines again, but I wouldn't for readability reasons.
6. Recognise that empty strings are falsey and all other strings are truthy, so simplify the `name != ""` check:

   ```
   greeting = f"Hi, {name}!" if name else "Hey there!"
   ```

And of course, instead of `raise NameError` you'd return some different message, as in your fixed code:

```
def say_hi(english: bool, name: str) -> str:
    if not english:
        return "I speak only English, sorry."

    greeting = f"Hi, {name}!" if name else "Hey there!"
    return greeting + "foo bar"
```

Thus we have condensed *six* logic branches into one and a half (tongue in cheek).

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with

```
def say_hi(english: bool, name: str) -> str:
    if name != "" and english:
        greeting = f"Hi, {name}!"
    elif name == "" and english:
        greeting = "Hey there!"
    return greeting + "foo bar" if english else /*greeting*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def say_hi(english: bool, name: str) -> str:
    if name != "":
        if english: #   return True
            greeting = f"Hi, {name}!"
    else:
        if english: # return True
            greeting = "Hey there!"
    if english: #return True
        greeting = greeting + "foo bar"
    return greeting
```

that's why when you call the function with False been passed as English will raise an error , cause all the if statements you wrote will always return True

To avoid this add if statement block the handle english when it's Flase like this

```
def say_hi(english: bool, name: str) -> str:
    
    if name != "" and english:
            greeting = f"Hi, {name}! foo bar" 
    elif english:
            greeting = "Hey there!"
        
    else:
        greeting = "False"
```